# Duda con espacios y paso de parametros (variables de php) a python

Tags: php, python, python-2.7

Verán soy principiante en python y php y de practica me dejaron que creara archivos de texto pasando las variables capturadas en un  en un formulario  como parámetros a python y lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
shell_exec("python /var/www/html/generartxt.py $nombre $Apat $Amat $edad $tel $email $calle $num $colonia");
```

aqui le mando las variables como parametro y en el script de python las recibo asi:

```
nombre = sys.argv[1]
```

y todo bien puedo generar el archivo con el contenido de todas las variables pero aquí mi duda

Cuando le meto dos nombres por ejemplo "Luis David" a la variable "nombre" en php no hay problema pero la mando como parámetro de python y al tener espacio me la detecta como otro argumento/parámetro diferente es decir en `argv[1]` queda Luis y en `argv[2]` queda David y requiero que los dos juntos estén en `argv[1]` y me afecta el formato en el que requiero escribir el archivo txt , habrá alguna forma de que tome esos dos nombres incluyendo el espacio como un solo argumento/parámetro?

Comment: basta con que agregues `"` a los argumentos, para indicarle a la shell que son un solo argumento. `shell_exec('python /var/www/html/generartxt.py "$nombre" "$Apat" "$Amat" "$edad" "$tel" "$email" "$calle" "$num" "$colonia"');`

Comment: no me funciono amigo

Answer (score 1):

Para probar podemos partir de un simple script Python que se limita a retornar la lista de argumentos que le llegan:

```
# test.py
import sys

sys.stdout.write(str(sys.argv[1:]))
sys.stdout.flush()
sys.exit(0)
```

Como es de esperar si pasamos cadenas con espacios, cada espacio se usa como delimitador:

> ```
> php > $nombre = "Stack Overflow";
> php > $apellidos = "foo baar";
> php > $output = shell_exec("python test.py $nombre $apellidos");    
> php > echo $output;              
> ['Stack', 'Overflow', 'foo', 'baar']
> ```

Para evitarlo podemos simplemente usar comillas dobles para la cadena que representa el comando y escapar con comillas simples los argumentos con espacios:

> ```
> php > $nombre = "Stack Overflow";
> php > $apellidos = "foo baar"; 
> php > $output = shell_exec("python test.py '$nombre' '$apellidos'");
> php > echo $output;              
> ['Stack Overflow', 'foo baar']
> ```

No puedes invertir el orden de las comilla en el ejemplo anterior, en PHP a diferencia de Python, no es lo mismo `'Hola me llamo $nombre'` que `"Hola me llamo $nombre"`. Para empezar,en el primer caso no se evalúa `$nombre`, para más información ver la documentación:

- [Cadenas de caracteres (Strings)](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php)

Si usamos comillas simples si que podríamos concatenar por ejemplo:

> ```
> php > $output = shell_exec('python test.py "'.$nombre.'" "'.$apellidos.'"');
> ```

Pero no es muy estético ni legible y no es muy difícil terminar metiendo la pata en cuanto tengamos unos cuantos argumentos...

No obstante lo mejor es usar usar [`escapechellarg`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.escapeshellarg.php) que hace esto por nosotros, además de solventar otras situaciones similares, sanitizando la cadena apropiadamente en función del sistema:

> ```
> php > $nombre = escapeshellarg("Stack Overflow");
> php > $apellidos = escapeshellarg("foo baar");
> php > $output = shell_exec("python test.py $nombre $apellidos");
> php > echo $output;
> ['Stack Overflow', 'foo baar']
> ```

Comment: Muchas gracias , me sirvio con las comillas simples . Saludos